# Unbalanced Feistel network function

Tags: feistel-network

I am trying to understand how an unbalanced Feistel network works. I came across this image: [image]

It says that the function takes $b$ bits to $y$ bits. Which works on the first step, however clearly doesn't on the next one.
What am I not getting?
If you always apply the function to the side with $b$ bits would that break the cypher? I am guessing it does.

Comment: The image is misleading. It is still taking b bits. You can get it from $b$ msb.

Comment: @kelalaka what does "$b$ msb" mean exactly?

Comment: $b$  Most Significant Bits.

Comment: @kelalaka and do these bits become a prefix or a suffix to the $y$ bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let formalize it

- Round function $R:\{0,1\}^b \to \{0,1\}^y$ (This is bad naming, $F$ was better here as in DES)
- Input to each round is $b+y$ bit register/array $I$.
- Output of each round $O = (R(\texttt{MSB}(b,I)) \oplus \texttt{LSB}(y,I)) \mathbin\| \texttt{MSB}(b,I)$

Therefore $O$ is again $b+y$ bits register/array as an input to next round.

---

- $\texttt{MSB}(b,I)$ the **M**ost **S**ignificant $b$ **B**its of register $I$.
- $\texttt{LSB}(y,I)$ the **L**east **S**ignificant $y$ **B**its of register $I$.

---

**Example**

Let $I=\texttt{[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]}$ be 16-bit register then

- $\texttt{MSB}(3,I) = \texttt{[0,1,1]}$, and
- $\texttt{LSB}(12,I) = \texttt{[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]}$

Note that here we used binary representation for $I$, not the array repsentation.